# Disable JS compiling in EmberJS / EmberCLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The javascript compiler of EmberJS/EmberCLI is really slowing down my development so I like to switch it off for now.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean the live reload capability? Or the Babel transpiler?

Comment: This was on an earlier version of EmberCLI, the whole compile process is changed now and works pretty fast :)